# How to bring up old version WAS after migrating it to new version via migration toolkit?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-6.1

i did the WAS migration from V7 to V8 through IBM migration toolkit. I set `disable the dmgr of previous version' during migration. Everything is fine finally. The WAS V8 works very well.
  However, once i tried to bring up my V7 again, it failed and could be up. I indeed closed all the WAS V8 process before operating V7. 
  Does anybody know how to start up my V7?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Paste the exact steps and the exact error message received.

Answer (score 0):

If you have both WAS V7 and V8 co-existing on the same physical systems then you may want to make sure ports are unique between 2 installs , also during migration process time WAS migration process rename serverindex.xml file to serverindex.xml.disabled so you will need to remove that ".disabled" extension.

Note : Make sure you bring one environment either V7 or V8 at a time .

Check following link for more details :

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.migration.nd.doc%2Fae%2Ftmig_rollback.html

Hope that helps.
VT, opinions are my own and not those of my employer